# NextJS API Endpoint Error - 'API resolved without sending a response for /api/foo, this may result in stalled requests.'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, fetch-api

This is the code I am using

```js
// function calling the api endpoint within a button onClick event handler
async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/foo', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  const responseData = await response.json()
}

// /api/foo.js
import { ref, uploadString } from 'firebase/storage'
import { storage } from './firebase'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const data = req.body
  const storageRef = ref(storage, data.ID)
  const uploadTask = uploadString(storageRef, 
      JSON.stringify(data.object)
    ).then(snapshot => { 
      res.status(200).json(
        { message: 'Saved!', severity: 'success' })
      res.end()
    }
  ) 
}
```

When a request is sent to the above API endpoint, the console in vscode shows that a request was sent with this error: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/foo, this may result in stalled requests.`

What does this mean and how is it fixed?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** - added `async` to `handler` function, but error still showing

Comment: handler function should be `async`

Comment: I have tried this but the error still occurs